# Please explain the declaration of CryptoJS

Tags: javascript

So, going through some malware I see that CryptoJS is declared like so:

```
var CryptoJS = CryptoJS || function(u, p) {
    var d = {},
        l = d.lib = {},
        s = function() {},
        ....stackoverflow doesnt allow me to paste all of the code...
        _createHmacHelper: function(a) {
            return function(b, e) {
                return (new n.HMAC.init(a,
                    e)).finalize(b)
            }
        }
    });
    var n = d.algo = {};
    return d
}(Math);
```

What I dont understand is this line:

`var CryptoJS = CryptoJS || function(u, p)...`

Why not simply:

`var CryptoJS = function(u, p)...`

Comment: It's called a polyfill. The point is, if a previous declaration already defined it, then it will short-circuit and skip the polyfill definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's commonly called a *polyfill* definition and it's very common in javascript. If a previous declaration already defined `CryptoJS` then it will skip what comes after the `||`, that is, the definition.